# Android Studio import settings not working

Tags: android

I have a problem with importing codestyle. I go to import settings and choose the right .jar file and it says it's sucessfully imported and prompted me to restart, but when I restart IDE the settings are nowhere to be found. On my other pc import  is working though. I tried using rar and copying files manually but that doesn't work either. I even tried with administrator mode, still doesn't work. I couldn't found any solution online. I'm using Android Studio 2.1.3.

Comment: what version of Android Studio u have

Comment: I'm using android studio 2.1.3.